# synchronization for get and set methods

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm newbie in Java threads and i need your help.

```
public enum IndicatorTimestamp {
    instance;
    private JSONObject indicatorTmsUTC;

    public void setIndicatorTimestamps(JSONObject indicatorTmsUTC) {
        this.indicatorTmsUTC = indicatorTmsUTC;
    }

    public String getUtcTmsForTag(String tag) {
        try {
            if (indicatorTmsUTC != null) {
                return indicatorTmsUTC.getString(tag);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I need to lock `indicatorTmsUTC`object. Is it ok, if i added `synchronized` word for both methods.
`public synchronized void setIndicatorTimestamps` and 
`public synchronized String getUtcTmsForTag`. 
Or there are other solutions?

Comment: You could run into problems here. IndicatorTimestamp will be thread-safe, but JSONObject may not be. It's not immutable - its state could be changed by another thread at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronized on your property to lock it while you use it.
If you want more fine tuned locking like read-write lock I recommend you to look at [java concurrent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)

It provides tools for replacing totally the crude synchronized keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- use synchronized both on the getter and the setter
- use a Lock both both in the getter and the setter
- use a ReadWriteLock, by using the read Lock in the getter and the write Lock in the setter

The advantage of the third solution is that you can have simultaneous threads reading at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Something like this

```
public void setIndicatorTimestamps(JSONObject indicatorTmsUTC) {
   synchronized(indicatorTmsUTC) {
         this.indicatorTmsUTC = indicatorTmsUTC;     
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not bad. As there is no any shared variable there will be no any deadlock situation. Anyway it will be better to have a synchronized block rather than synchronized method.

```
synchronized (object reference) {  //this instance is OK 
//code block   
}
```

Comment: i need to use synchronized block for getter and setter? Or only for setter?

Comment: It will be enough to use for setter method only. Use indicatorTmsUTC as the object lock then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll run into problems with the mutability of `JSONObject`. While adding your proposed synchronization will make your `enum` thread-safe, the same cannot be said of the `JSONObject` itself.

My suggested course of action will be to create an immutable class to encapsulate the data to be converted to JSON, and have that class as an instance variable in your `enum` instead of the `JSONObject`. Then do the JSON serialization in your `getUtcTmsForTag` method.